# react-intl: Missing locale data for locale: "undefined". Using default locale: "en" as fallback

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React v15.4, react-intl v2.2.3

In my /lang/en.json :

```
{
  "greeting": "Hello, World!"
}
```

And my /pages/about.js :

```
import React from 'react'
import {FormattedMessage} from 'react-intl'
import pageWithIntl from '../components/PageWithIntl'
import Layout from '../components/Layout'

export default pageWithIntl(({intl}) => (
  <Layout>
    <h1 className="page-title">About Page</h1>
    <p>
      <FormattedMessage id='greeting' defaultMessage='Hello, World!' />
    </p>
  </Layout>
))
```

When I load the page the "Hello, World!" - Text is correctly displayed. 
But in the console I'm getting

> [React Intl] Missing locale data for locale: "undefined". Using
>   default locale: "en" as fallback.

When I reload the page. How can I add the missing locale data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should wrap you main component (usually it named `<App/ >`) into `<IntlProvider>` middleware and set `locale` prop.

```
<IntlProvider locale='en'>
   <App/ >
</ IntlProvider>
```

or React automatically set `locale: 'en'` and throw you warning

> [React Intl] Missing locale data for locale: "undefined". Using
>   default locale: "en" as fallback.